# ADO.net Entity Framework: Update only certian properties on a detached entity

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, ado.net

I want to update an entity without loading the entity from the database first.

I've accomplished this but only by knowing all of the entities properties and then using the "attachto" method.

My issues is i don't want my app to need to remember all of the properties. Example:

```
 Dim customerEntitiy As New shopper
 customerEntitiy.shopper_id = CustomerData.CustomerID
 customerEntitiy.market_code = CustomerData.MarketSector
 customerEntitiy.email = CustomerData.Email
 customerEntitiy.modified = DateTime.Now
 context.AttachTo("shopper", customerEntitiy)
 context.SaveChanges()
```

That entity also has a "created" field on it. I don't want to pass this "created" date all the way through my n-tier app. How can i just "not update" that field when saving to the database? Thanks!
Paul

Comment: Although it's possible to do what you want, it's not recomended because the Entity may not be linked dierectly to tables. For instance I use entites associated with views, and updated using procedures. This approach would have very undesired effects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, basically you use a stub instead, attach it, then only set the props you want to be updated. The entity framework will only update the things changed.

```
Dim customerEntitiy As New commerce_shopper
customerEntitiy.shopper_id = CustomerData.CustomerID 'this is the primary key'
context.AttachTo("commerce_shopper", customerEntitiy)
customerEntitiy.market_code = CustomerData.MarketSector
customerEntitiy.email = CustomerData.Email
customerEntitiy.modified = DateTime.Now
context.SaveChanges()
```

This bypasses the "created" date field.

Comment: can you let us know what you mean by 'stub' in this context. We are also having the same issue and would like to know how you solved it.

Comment: Basically you are creating a new db object, then assign the primary key to it (.shopper_id = PK), then use the AttachTo to put it on the context. Change your stuff, and hit save.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to update an entity using save changes, without first loading it from the database. The code that you have will generate an insert statement, not an update.

You may be able to accomplish what you are trying to do using stored procedures, that only update spesified fileds.

Comment: Can i do this through Linq to Sql instead?

Comment: I have not used Linq to SQL, but I think that you will run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/89b7087a-1b08-4fe0-9cc3-68986fe89a74