# Entity Framework 4 - Where to put "ApplyCurrentValues" Logic?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework-4, unit-of-work

I'm using the "**[stub technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343530/entityframework-net-4-update-entity-with-a-simple-method/1347775#1347775)**" to **update** my POCO's (used in a detached context, ASP.NET MVC).

This is the code i currently have in my controller (which works):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Review review)
{
   Review originalReview = _userContentService.FindById(review.PostId) as Review;
   var ctx = _unitOfWork as MySqlServerObjectContext;
   ctx.ApplyCurrentValues("MyEntities.Posts", review);
   _unitOfWork.Commit();
   // ..snip - MVC stuff..
}
```

As you can see, there is code smell everywhere. :)

A few points:

1. I use Dependency Injection (interface-based) for basically everything
2. I use the Unit of Work pattern to abstract ObjectContext and provide persistence across multiple repositories
3. Currently my **IUnitOfWork** interface has only 1 method: `void Commit();`
4. Controller have `IUserContentService` and `IUnitOfWork` inject by DI
5. `IUserContentService` calls `Find` in Repositories, which use the `ObjectContext`.

These are two things i don't like with my above code:

1. I don't want to cast the **IUnitOfWork** as `MySqlServerObjectContext`.
2. I don't want the Controller to have to care about `ApplyCurrentValues`

I basically want my code to look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Review review)
{
   _userContentService.Update(review);
   _unitOfWork.Commit();
   // ..snip - MVC stuff..
}
```

Any ideas how i can do that? (or something similar).

I already have smarts to work out the entity set name based on the type (combination of generics, pluralization), so don't worry too much about that.

But **i'm wondering where the best place to put `ApplyCurrentValues` is**? It doesn't seem appropriate to put it in the `IUnitOfWork` interface, as this is a persistence (EF) concern. For the same reason it doesn't belong in the Service. If i put it in my `MySqlServerObjectContext` class (makes sense), where would i call this from, as nothing directly has access to this class - it is injected via DI when something requests `IUnitOfWork`.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

I have a solution below using the stub technique, but the problem is if i had retrieved the entity i am updating beforehand, it throws an exception, stating an entity with that key already exists.

Which makes sense, although i'm not sure how can resolve this?

Do i need to "check if the entity is already attached, if not, attach it?"

Can any EF4 experts out there help?

**EDIT**

Nevermind - found the solution, see answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out - wasn't easy, so i'll try to explain best i can. (for those who care)

**Controller Relevant Code:**

```
// _userContentService is IUserContentService
_userContentService.Update(review);
```

So, my controller calls a method called `Update` on `IUserContentService`, passing through the strongly-typed `Review` object.

**User Content Service Relevant Code**

```
public void Update(Post post)
{
   // _userContentRepository is IPostRepository
   _userContentRepository.UpdateModel(post);
}
```

So, my service calls a method called `UpdateModel` on `IPostRepository`, passing through the strongly-typed `Review` object.

Now, here is the tricky part.

I actually have **no specific Repositories**. I have a *generic repository* called `GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T>`, which handles **all the different repositories.**

So when something requests a `IPostRepository` (which my service was doing), DI would give it a `GenericRepository<Post>`.

But now, i give it a `PostRepository`:

```
public class PostRepository : GenericRepository<Post>, IPostRepository
{
   public void UpdateModel(Post post)
   {
      var originalPost = CurrentEntitySet.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PostId == post.PostId);
      Context.ApplyCurrentValues(GetEntityName<Post>(), post);
   }
}
```

And because the class *derives* from **GenericRepository**, it inherits all the core repository logic (Find, Add, etc).

At first, i tried to put that **UpdateModel** code in the **GenericRepository** class itself (and then i wouldn't have needed this specific repository), but the problem is the logic to retrieve the existing entity is based on a specific entity key, which the `GenericRepository<T>` would not know about.

But the end result is the *stitching* is hidden deep down in the depths of the data layer, and i end up with a really clean Controller.

**EDIT**

This "stub technique" also works:

```
public void UpdateModel(Post post)
{
   var stub = new Review {PostId = post.PostId};
   CurrentEntitySet.Attach(stub);
   Context.ApplyCurrentValues(GetEntityName<Post>(), post);
}
```

But the problem is because **Post** is abstract, i cannot instantiate and therefore would have to check the type of Post and create stubs for *every single* derived type. Not really an option.

**EDIT 2 (LAST TIME)**

Okay, got the "stub technique" working with abstract classes, so now the concurrency issue is solved.

I added a generic type parameter to my **UpdateModel** method, and the special **[new() constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5(VS.80).aspx)**.

**Implementation:**

```
public void UpdateModel<T>(T post) where T : Post, new()
{
   var stub = new T { PostId = post.PostId };
   CurrentEntitySet.Attach(stub);
   Context.ApplyCurrentValues(GetEntityName<Post>, post);
}
```

**Interface:**

```
void UpdateModel<T>(T post) where T : Post, new();
```

This prevents me from having to figure out the type of T manually, prevents concurrency issues and also prevents an extra trip to the DB.

Pretty groovy.

**EDIT 3 (i thought the last time was the last time)**

The above "stub technique" works, but if i retrieve the object beforehand, it throws an exception stating an entity with that key already exists in the OSM.

Can anyone advise how to handle this?

**EDIT 4 (OK - this is it!)**

I found the solution, thanks to this SO answer: [Is is possible to check if an object is already attached to a data context in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715501/is-is-possible-to-check-if-an-object-is-already-attached-to-a-data-context-in-ent/1716109#1716109)

I had tried to "check if the entity is attached" using the following code:

```
ObjectStateEntry entry;
CurrentContext.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(entity, out entry);
```

But it always returned **null**, even through when i explored the OSM i could see my entity there with the same key.

But this code works:

```
CurrentContext.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(CurrentContext.CreateEntityKey(CurrentContext.GetEntityName<T>(), entity), out entry)
```

Maybe because i'm using Pure POCO's, the OSM had trouble figuring out the entity key, who knows.

Oh and one other thing i added - so that i don't have to add a specific repository for each entity, i created an attribute called "**[EntityKey]**" (public property attribute).

All POCO's must have 1 public property decorated with that attribute, or i throw an exception in my repository module.

So my generic repository then looks for this property in order to create/setup the stub.

Yes - it uses reflection, but it's clever reflection (attribute-based) and i'm already using reflection for plularization of entity set names from T.

Anyway, problem solved - all working fine now!

Comment: Looks interesting, nice of you to have posted such a detailed description of your solution. One issue, however - doesn't **Attach** throw an exception if a *Post* with the same *PostId* is already attached? E.g. if you do a *GetAll()* against the same context at some point earlier and all the Posts are already attached?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point - i'll test that out by doing exactly that (when i get in the office on monday). If so i might have to check is an entity is already attached, though i'm not really sure how to do that. (esp since im using pure pocos)

Comment: @Yakimych - dang, your right. If i retrieve that object beforehand it throws the exception. Any ideas? Is there a way we can "check if an entity is already attached to the graph?" I might have to ask another question.

Comment: We use `CurrentContext.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(entity, out entry);` as in the other SO question you found. Seems to work fine, but we use POCOs with proxies. Nice post, anyway. Upvote!

Comment: Yeah, didnt work for me that way - we're using pure POCO's. I could see the entity there with the same entity key, but it did not retrieve it. It's all sorted now anyway. Now i keep going until i run into the next problem. :)